# Gradle + Box2D b2PolygonShape+ Java(TM) SE binary

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, tween

I've ran a test gradle project fine, just displaying the badlogic games logo. The problem is when I try to launch my own gradle project setup having added the tween jars. This is the message displayed in the eclipse console:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      run
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:classes UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:run
game dimensions in UWGAME: 272.0, 483.55557

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-
box2d/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp, Line 384

Expression: m_count >= 3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 17.454 secs
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Build finished succesfully!
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 17 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

What this does is:

Java(TM) Platform SE Binary has stopped working

Any Idea how I can solve this one?

Thank you for considering this question.

Antoine,

**EDIT**

**SOLVED: Never set a shape.setRadius(float Radius) when shape = new PolygonShape, in this case shape needs to be a  = new CircleShape(); anyhow .setRadius just shouldn't be a method for Polygonshape objects.. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED: Never set a shape.setRadius(float Radius) when shape = new PolygonShape, in this case shape needs to be a = new CircleShape(); anyhow .setRadius just shouldn't be a method for Polygonshape objects.. **

Answer (score 0):

You should check the PPM value define in your constant. By which you have divided the PolygonShape.setAsBox(x/2/Coonstant.ppm,y/2/Constant.ppm)..
ppm value must be in float.